# Trigger event after scrolling past element javascript only

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a javascript only solution to detect when my window has scrolled up past a certain element (like a div) and then trigger an event. In particular I need to show a navbar once I've scrolled past this element.

I can't use Jquery or other libraries. Plain JS.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673293/trigger-event-when-scroll-past-bottom-of-element

Comment: Those solutions use jquery.

Comment: Oops fair sorry, but there are tons of examples that do use javascript

Comment: But what is the problem of using jQuery?

Comment: [Trigger events when the window is scrolled to certain positions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5672320/215552) only has JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a **[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LdhdLzo0/)**

You need to select the element that you want as the target.

```
var someElement = document.querySelector('whatever');
```

Then you need set an `scroll` event listener on the `window` object itself, which fires every time the user scrolls, then simply run a `if` statment to check if the element from the top of the screen is greater or equal to 0, if `true` run the following block of code.

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    //TOP
    if(someElement.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0){
        console.log("TRIGGER: top of div reached.");
    }
    //BOTTOM
    if(someElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= 0){
        console.log("TRIGGER: bottom of div reached.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I need. I also updated the fiddle with how I'd implement a fixed navbar.