# Animated images and content on scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

How I can archive this animation in WordPress or custom PHP shortcode?

[image]

Those images and content will be sourced from Custom Fields.

The whole section needs to show only one image and one text on the right side at a time, but when the user starts scrolling then the next image should slide down and cover the previous one. Text on right side should hide and reveal next one. ( while the whole website scrolling disabled ).

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673293/trigger-event-when-scroll-past-bottom-of-element

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I've tried the solution above, but this is not what I want. Any idea how I can solve this?